# Using form method="post" to assign a php variable dynamically

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to run a specific database query based on what value is selected in a select drop down. The current code I have isn't running the queries.

My current code looks like this:

main-search.php

```
<form action="" method="post">
   <div class="search-container">
       <input type="text" id="search_input" placeholder="">
       <select name="search-by">
           <option value="symptom">Symptom</option>
           <option value="language">Language</option>
       </select>
   </div>
</form>

<?php   
    session_start();
    $searchBy = $_POST['search-by'];
    $_SESSION['search_type'] = $searchBy;
?>
```

search.php

```
<?php
session_start();

$queryType = $_SESSION['search_type'];

if ($queryType == "symptom") {
        $searchQuery = $db->query("SELECT * FROM Symptoms WHERE symptom_name ORDER BY symptom_name ASC");
    }
    else if ($queryType == "language") {
        $searchQuery = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `Language` WHERE language_name ORDER BY language_name ASC");
    }

?>
```

I have tried changing the code in main-search.php to...

```
<?php   
    session_start();
    $searchBy = $_POST['search-by'];
    $_SESSION['search_type'] = "symptom";
?>
```

and it works as intended, running the first query, so that's why I'm assuming I'm doing something wrong with the post form and assigning the $searchBy value.

I'm new to php, so any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: is it correct? `WHERE symptom_name ???`??

Comment: `print_r($_POST)` check what are you getting after submission and share the result, also check your `WHERE` clause. maybe u forgot to close form tag in original code or have multiple forms. is it your original code?

Comment: You have `action=""` which posts to the same page `main-search.php`, how do you ever get to `search.php`???

Comment: @AbraCadaver: OP is not using any post input in this file `search.php` he is storing the data on same file. which is `main-search.php`, actually its not a complete example, and i am assuming, its related to undefined index error also.

Comment: @devpro `main-search.php` is a form that posts to itsself, where and when is `search.php` ever executed???

Comment: you must need to use `isset()` here `$searchBy = $_POST['search-by'];` either form posted or not.

Comment: search.php is a another file where he just want to get SESSION variable i think from main-search.php @AbraCadaver

Comment: @AbraCadaver: when he tried to hard coded this value `$_SESSION['search_type'] = "symptom";` its work, it means, something wrong with form. or maybe he is facing undefined index error

Comment: Add `<button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>` inside your form, pick an item from the dropdown and click the button.

Comment: @devpro the query is correct in my code. yes, I just want to get the session variable from main-search.php to search.php. I dont quite understand what you mean by using isset()?

Comment: in main-search.php, use this `print_r($_POST)` after `session_start();` and share the  result

Answer (score 0):

It's probably best to avoid Session variables for this purpose, as session variables are used to store/pass information from page to page in PHP (such as login status).

From my deduction you are trying to change this PHP variable dynamically when the user changes the `<select>` option. As PHP is a server-side script this will not work, if you need something to change without reloading the page you will need to use a client-side script (e.g. Javascript/jQuery). For example (in jQuery):

```
$('select[id="search-type"]').on("change", function(){
    //Do work
});
```

However, if I understand you correctly, your best bet is to just use HTTP POST variables (accessed by `$_POST` in PHP), for example:

`main-search.php`:

```
<form action="search.php" method="post">
    <div class="search-container">
       <input type="text" id="search_input" placeholder="">
       <select name="search_type" id="search-type">
           <option value="symptom">Symptom</option>
           <option value="language">Language</option>
       </select>
       <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

`search.php`:

```
<?php

$queryType = $_POST['search_type'];

if ($queryType == "symptom") {
    $searchQuery = $db->query("SELECT * FROM Symptoms WHERE symptom_name ORDER BY symptom_name ASC");
}
else if ($queryType == "language") {
    $searchQuery = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `Language` WHERE language_name ORDER BY language_name ASC");
}

?>
```